# Is extra CPU on USB dongle possible?

Tags: computer-architecture, cluster, dongle

Is it theoretically possible to build a local cluster for distributed computing using any type of a dongle plugged into a USB or HDMI port, and connecting to the Linux console inside over SSH just like to another node in the computing cluster?  Are there inherent limitations in such an approach that would preclude this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but the USB dongle won't be "just a CPU" it would need to be a full computer. There are "computer on a stick" form factors out there, most of them run on the Atom processor.

To use one as a "plug in dongle" you need to find one that mimics some kind of IO port, like a usb network card, then your main computer can use this network card to connect to the USB computer. This will likely be harder to find.

Comment: All in all such a combo would be rather a specialized piece of hardware, right?